# Directly call Activities and Sub-orchestrations of Azure Durable Functions

Tags: c#, azure-durable-functions

Is there any way to directly call activity of a durable function other than through another specialized durable function?

For example, I have a durable function `D`, calling activities `A1`, `A2` and sub-orchestration `S`.

In other scenarios I don't need whole logic of `D` and I'd rather directly call `A1` or `S`. Ideally I'd like those to have separate queues of tasks they need to process (AFAIK, durable functions actually work this way, so in fact `A1` and `S` do have queues of tasks). `D` can use that queue, and I also want to manually push messages there whenever I need from other pieces of code (not durable functions).

The only solution I see for now is wrapping each activity I need into separate primitive durable functions `DA1`, `DS`, which would just forward the call to corresponding activity. But that's obviously an overhead and reduces system reliability. Is there a better way of calling `A1` or `S` directly?

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported at the moment. But there is an open issue tracking this feature. Kindly see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/160